# What is the meaning of "shell lot" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading a short story, and I have no idea with the expression "*shell lot*" in the following sentence. Can anyone help me figure out the meaning?
Thank you.

> There was a **shell lot** in front of eight white cottages spaced out along a tiny creek running diagonally through the property. These were the cabanas, she figured.

Comment: Likely a parking lot surfaced with crushed shells like oyster shells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!